# Is it possible to do visual changes in power bi?

Tags: powerbi-embedded

I was wondering if it's possible to do visual change with power bi embedded?  For example, let's say that I have a line graph that points to a specific data source.  Is it possible to change the line graph to a bar graph for example within the iframe via power bi sdk?

Thanks,
Derek

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Visual authoring is currently not supported in Power BI Embedded.
Visual size, location and visibility - however - is covered by bookmarks:
https://github.com/Microsoft/PowerBI-JavaScript/wiki/Bookmarks

Comment: Is there plans to support this?